How to tell Android that 80% battery is actually 0%
I have a phone whose battery is dying at 80%. How can I calibrate Android so that it's aware of the actual battery capacity? I have root access.
To be clear, I'm not asking to increase the capacity or re-calibrate the battery itself, only make a change to Android so it can reflect the actual battery capacity.
I'm pretty sure the battery is fake since even when it was brand new it would die at 30%, so I have no expectations of getting more life out of the battery itself.

I am no dev or experienced user, but I think a battery level notification like this would help? There you can set the "needs to charge now" notification to pop up when the system battery level drops to 85%, to tell you to unplug at 98%, which is the upper limit.
Afterall, if the 80% is actually 0, then the battery should be pretty swollen as well. Replace if you can.(May I know which model is it?)
